# Unit Test C# Can we test catch block?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, try-catch, xunit

let's say i have a method that logins in;

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    try
    {
        //my codes..
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        _sLogger.Slack(exp)
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

i have tested all controllers and  methods but i can't test the catch block? i can't throw a exception, how can i do that?

i have tried like this but that doesn't work for me:

```
public void_WithInvalidData_ThenBadRequest()
{
    authController.UnAuthrorize();
    var result=(BadRequestResult)authController.Login();
    Assert.True(result.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    authController.Authorize();
}
```

Comment: Normally, you would do that by throwing an exception on a mock in your try block. You do not show that part, nor do you show whether you're using any mocking framework.

Comment: Why you can't throw an exception? Could you share the full method here?

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    try
    {
       if (conditions) throw new Exception($"Message"); // throw an exception
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        _sLogger.Slack(exp)
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```